# "printf" and "scanf", something wrong with stream

Tags: c

So here is my code.

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char c;
    size_t place;
    while (1) {
        scanf("%c %u", &c, &place);
        printf("%c\n", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled and ran program I expected to see terminal like this:

```
a 1
a
b 2
b
c 3
c
```

But I saw this:(some extra '\n')

```
a 1
a
b 2


b
c 3


c
```

Please help me find what I did wrong.

Comment: @user3121023 I think this comment is more useful than the answer itself

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. But could you please explain me why my expectations aren't correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
scanf(" %c %u", &c, &place);
      ^^--Add space here
```

instead of

```
scanf("%c %u", &c, &place);
```

Answer (score 2):

`printf("char is %c\n", c);` Adding some string before printing the received character will helps you to understand more clearly why its behaving like this. After your input some blank spaces or new line is entered, that is used in the next `scanf`. You can even print the ascii value of the charater like `printf("char is %d, %c", c, c);` and serach the ASCII value in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), to understand exactly which value (blanks or new line or tab) scanf has received mistakenly.

Keeping blankspace as first character in format string of `scanf` will helps to skip all leading blanks(including tabs and newline). Like `scanf(" %c %u", &c, &place);`